# How to change label on input focus when input comes after label?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="my-field">
    <label class="my-label">Label</label>
    <input class="my-input" value="input" />
</div>
```

```
#my-field{
}
.my-label {
}
.my-input{
}
```

Is there any way I can customize the CSS of .my-label when input is in focus without touching the HTML? There are multiple ways to select successor sibling elements. But any way to select predecessor(s)?

**Note:** There is a restriction in the project that HTML cannot be modified here. Everything has to be done in CSS only. No jQuery/JS either.

Comment: CSS can't travel up the DOM, as far as I know this is not possible with just CSS in the current HTML layout. The closest thing to a solution I can think of would be to hide your label and create a fake custom label of your own using pseudo elements.

Comment: No way without changing html, if you can change html a bit then its possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can do it without changing your HTML structure.

The `:focus-within` CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has received focus or contains an element that has received focus. In other words, it represents an element that is itself matched by the `:focus` pseudo-class or has a descendant that is matched by `:focus`

Note that example uses `:focus-within` on the entire form and on interior input-wrapping `<div>`.

Learn more about [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) selector.

```css
#my-field:focus-within .my-label {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-field">
    <label class="my-label">Label</label>
    <input class="my-input" value="input" />
</div>
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one input field in `#my-field`, you can try `:focus-within`:

```
#my-field:focus-within .my-label{ ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

No. there is unfortunately no predecessor selector in css

```
input:focus -+ label { ... }
```

would be lovely.

having the label after the input would be dooable:

```
input:focus + label { ... }
```

you could use some positioning to display before...

Answer (score -1):

In this case (since the input doesn't have any other siblings), you can use the sibling CSS selector ~.

```
input:focus ~ label {...}
```